# Why use "he include"?

Tags: grammar, sentence, writing-style

> To expect Daub to acknowledge critiques of tech thinking by women is to expect that `he include` not the most feminist or woke critiques of those philosophies, but the most trenchant ones.

- Why `he include` has been used? Under what circumstances is this allowed? What is the grammar behind it?

Source: https://www.nytimes.com/2020/10/13/books/review/what-tech-calls-thinking-adrian-daub.html

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. If I I understand the idea correctly, I can use *he would include* also. Right?

Comment: @Budu Gulo- No, the conditional is not the same as the subjunctive. 'Expect' has two different senses. "I expect the Sun will rise tomorrow" is not subjunctive. It is a prediction based on past experience. "I expect you to clean your bedroom" is almost a command. It implies obligation and requires action.

Comment: Yes; that (using 'would' or perhaps 'should') would be the usual way to express this in 'British English'. The 'indicative-in-place-of-the-subjunctive' is perhaps the most common of the three variants in 'BrE' (ie used most often by proficient speakers in the UK), but would not work here (and alter the intended meaning). Whether or not the term 'subjunctive' is properly used for English 'hypothetical structures', and the fact that the 'mandative subjunctive' is often preferred to the periphrastic and 'indicative-for-subjunctive' approaches by many in the States, has been discussed here before.

Comment: [Write to Govern](http://www.writetogovern.com.au/verbs-in-board-paper-recommendations/) has an article on the use of the 'mandative subjunctive': << The mandative subjunctive is used with clauses that often, but not always, begin with that and express a demand, requirement, request, recommendation or suggestion: (1) I suggest she leave the country. (2) It is recommended that the Board approve the policy. (4) I demand that he give me the book. >> [rearranged]. Guess where I feel 'We expect that he include the most trenchant examples' fits in. (But admittedly, I'd probably rephrase them all.)

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica would you give a detailed answer? I am little confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A brief explanation.  The verb "to expect" can be used either in the sense of "to predict" or "to require".

*I expect you will arrive soon.* (I *predict* that you  will arrive soon - indicative. This could mean that the person has phoned because they are lost. You reassure them that they will soon arrive.)

*I expect you to arrive soon.* (I require you (place you under an obligation) to arrive soon)

The above senses can be found in any good dictionary. See for example [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expect) -  Compare meanings 1a and 1c.

---

> To expect Daub to acknowledge critiques of tech thinking by women is
> to expect that he include not the most feminist or woke critiques of
> those philosophies, but the most trenchant ones.

In a comment you ask if "he would expect" could be substituted. I answered No. My reason is that the subjunctive *requires* him to include trenchant critiques. This inclusion is expected of him.

However, if you use "would", this *anticipates* that, **if** he were to acknowledge critiques of tech thinking, **then** he  would (of his own free will) include trenchant critiques.

I hope this helps.

Comment: "To expect Daub to acknowledge critiques .."  does it mean that the author's assumption is Daub is going to acknowledge critiques?

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer is that the implied phrase is "he would include", but "would" has been left out.  (I would tend to call this "elision", but in linguistics the term is mainly used for leaving out sounds, so it's best to avoid it here.)

(Ah, yes -- the "proper" term is "ellipsis".)

This practice is fairly common in English, but it would be hard to establish rules for when it should or shouldn't be done.  Mainly it's a matter of becoming familiar with the language.